# Parsing to a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a calander that can later be styled with CSS.  Here is the JS and HTML codes.  There is a CSS stylesheet as well but its just used for color and positioning.  In the Javascript, I would like to build the table based off the first and last days of the month and insert a new row at the end of each week.  As is the Javascript does nothing.  When you remove the first if statement, it seems to iterate only once. I'm not sure where I'm screwing up in trying to create the table.

```
function setDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  var month = today.getMonth();
  var day = today.getDate();
  document.getElementById("myDay").value = day;
  document.getElementById("myMonth").value = month;
  document.getElementById("myYear").value = year;
}

function buildCalendar() {
  var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("myYear").value, document.getElementById("myMonth").value, 1);
  var weekDay = firstDate.getDay();
  var theDate = firstDate.getDate();
  var theMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
  var theYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
  var newDay = new Date(theYear, theMonth + 1, 1);
  var lastDate = new Date(newDay - 1);
  var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();
  document.write("<table class='caltable' border='1'><tr><th>");
  document.write("<tr><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th>");
  document.write("</th></tr>");
  var col = 0;
  for (var i = theDate; i < lastDay + 1; i++) {
    if (col == 0) {
      document.write("<tr><td>" + i "</td>");
    }
    if (col == 6) {
      document.write("<td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
      col == 0;
    } else {
      document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
      col++;
    }
  }


  document.write("</table>");
}

function getMonthName() {
  var e = getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex;
  var monthName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  return monthName;
}
```

Here is the HTML file.  It's basically just a wrapper div with some other divs inside for holding the calendar eventually a scheduler, as well as the current date.  Right now I'm simply trying to get the the table (see the javascript) to build.  Ideally it would be in the div with the id "bottomLeft".

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./CSS/calendar.css"> 
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/task.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad = "setDate(); buildCalendar();">
        <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "left">  Left Div   </div>
        <div id = "right"> Right Div </div>
        <div id = "bottomLeft"> Shows calendar </div>
        <div id = "topLeft"> Day:<input id = "myDay" type="number" min = "1" max = "31">Month:<select id = "myMonth"><option value = "0">January</option> <option value = "1">February</option><option value = "2">March</option><option value = "3">April</option><option value = "4">May</option><option value = "5">June</option><option value = "6">July<option value = "7">August</option><option value = "8">September</option><option value = "9">October</option><option value = "10">November</option><option value = "11">December</option></select> Year:<input id = "myYear" type = "number" min = "100"> TopLeft Div shows form components for date  </div>
        <div id = "topRight"> Shows the form to add task </div>
        <div id = "bottomRight"> Show list of tasks </div>
            </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the mistakes Ceesie123456 mentioned, you need to remove the extra `<tr><th>` from the opening table tag string. As a means of getting the calendar into the bottomLeft div, you can use set the element's innerHTML property. Finally, you're missing a piece of logic which check for when the end of the calendar is not the end of a row, which means the table won't line up correctly. So, an example:

```
function buildCalendar(){
    var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("myYear").value, document.getElementById("myMonth").value, 1);
    var weekDay = firstDate.getDay();
    var theDate = firstDate.getDate();
    var theMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
    var theYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
    var newDay = new Date(theYear, theMonth + 1, 1);
    var lastDate = new Date(newDay - 1);
    var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();

    var tableString = ("<table class='caltable' border='1'>");
    tableString = tableString + ("<thead><tr><tr><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th></tr></thead>");
    tableString = tableString + "<tbody>";
    var col = 0;
    for (var i = theDate; i <= lastDay; i++)
    {
        if(col == 0)
        {
            tableString = tableString + ("<tr>");
        }
        tableString = tableString + "<td>" + i + "</td>";

        if (col == 6 || i == lastDay)
        {
            tableString = tableString + ("</tr>");
            col = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            col++;
        }
    }

    tableString = tableString + ("</tbody></table>");
    document.getElementById("bottomLeft").innerHTML = tableString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U made a few mistakes in ur Javascript code.

```
if (col == 6)
{
document.write("<td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
col == 0;  //this should be changed to col = 0; with col = 0; u set col to 0.
}
```

and

```
 if(col == 0)
{
document.write("<tr><td>" + i "</td>"); 
}
```

u should change it to:

```
if(col == 0)
{
document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>"); // combine string with variable and string.
}
```